# Debug Android with Unity

Tags: android, debugging, unity-game-engine, bluetooth

I'm trying to build an application for Android that is developed in Unity using the asset BTLibrary, which is available in the asset store.

I really need the possibility to check runtime, from the Unity console, if my Android is correctly receiving the data sent by an accelerometer.

Does anyone know how to debug an android application using Unity Remote?

Thank you for your kind attention
Best regards!!

PS I've seen that someone put this question as a duplicate but I have one more doubt. When I use Android it takes not as long as for Unity to build the app. I think that the reason is because of the graphic. Is there any way to compile only parts of the code and not the entire code everytime?

Comment: So you do want Attach MonoDevelop Debugger To An Android Device?

Comment: Yes, because I want to make a cube that rotates according to the MIMU rotation. So I need to verify runtime what's appening... I mean like you would do with the android logcat while receiving the bluetooth data when checking the values you are receiving and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you can simply connect your device using Unity Remote and use

`Update() { Debug.Log(input_variable); }`

For instance `Update() { Debug.Log(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")); }`

Comment: Mmmmm not sure that this can help me. I've tried something similar. But if I use an android tv box (my case) it doesn't work. The console doesn't show the android response